# How i can i fetch first row of the selected item?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I have fetched 2nd and 3rd columns from database in view in the list. Now whenever an option is selected i want to fetch the 1st column value corresponding to the the selected item from the database in a variable suppose std... How to implement this??

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/userinfo?user=root&password=admin");
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

resultset = statement.executeQuery("select * from item");

<select id = "item3" name = "item3" onchange = "display_selection()">
    <%while(resultset.next()){%> 
    <option>
        <%= resultset.getString(2)%>
        <%= resultset.getString(3)%> 
    </option>
    <%}%>

    <script>
        function display_selection() {
            var e = document.getElementById("item3").value;
            var val = document.getElementById("item");
            val.value = e;
        } 
    </script> 
</select></font>
<div class = "item2">
    <input type = "text" name = "item" id = "item" value = "" size = "165" disabled = "disabled" /> 
</div>
</h5>
```

Now to assign that first column data corresponding to the particular selected ID what should be the code??

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please click the `<>` snippet editor, post html and JavaScript only (render the HTML) and provide example input with expected output in a [mcve]

Comment: In the selection id, look there are 2 parameters in resultset.getString for displaying the list dropdown list (thats 2nd and 3rd column from database). Now if i select anyone list item, I want to display the first column data corresponding to the selected item...

Answer (score 0):

It is a little unclear what you are asking. Perhaps it is as simple as this?

```js
document.getElementById("item3").onchange=function() {
  document.getElementById("item").value=this.value;
}
```

```html
<select id="item3" name="item3">
<% while(resultset.next()){ %>
  <option value="<%= resultset.getString(1)%>"><%= resultset.getString(2)%>  <%= resultset.getString(3)%> </option>
<% } %>
</select>
<div class="item2"><input type="text" name="item" id="item" value="" size="165" disabled="disabled" /></div>
```

Alternatively do this:

```
var result = [<% while(resultset.next()){ %>
  ["<%= resultset.getString(1)%>","<%= resultset.getString(2)%>","<%= resultset.getString(3)%>"]
<% } %>];
```

Then you can use script to add the options to the select and later use

```
document.getElementById("item").value=result[sel.selectedIndex][0]
```

Comment: In the selection id, look there are 2 parameters in resultset.getString for displaying the list dropdown list (thats 2nd and 3rd column from database). Now if i select anyone list item, I want to display the first column data corresponding to the selected item...

Comment: I did. If this is not the solution then I do not understand what you want

Comment: According to your code you are showing the values of 3 columns in list view.. I have no prblem with list view.. But suppose I want the value of only 1st column [resultset.getString(1)]of the selected item and assign it to a variable..

Comment: Then create an array `var result = [<% while(resultset.next()){ %>
  ["<%= resultset.getString(1)%>","<%= resultset.getString(2)%>","<%= resultset.getString(3)%>"]
<% } %>];` then you can use script to add the options to the select and later use `result[sel.selectedIndex][0]`

Comment: I didnt get you. Can you be a little more clear..  `<select id = "item3" name = "item3" onchange = "display_selection()">
    <%while(resultset.next()){%> 
    <option>
        <%= resultset.getString(2)%>
        <%= resultset.getString(3)%> 
    </option>
    <%}%> `  tell me a replacement for this